# How do databases efficiently handle (intermediate) results?

Tags: database, performance

Assume a query that performs (multiple) joins. A join operation can lead to both, more columns and more rows in the (intermediate) result.

It is easy to imagine an intermediate 2D format that "grows" from join to join. However, data will be copied around a lot in memory.

I wonder if this is actually done in efficient database implementations or if there is different strategy in use?

e: For example there are two obvious ways to produce intermediate tables (2D): such that data of each row or data of each column is consecutive in memory. depending on operations, each arrangement may have benefits or drawbacks (scans of less data vs access with bad locality). Surely, there are more advance variants as well.

Comment: I woud suggest you read a book like this for your preferred database: http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Server-Internals-Developer-Reference/dp/0735658560/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1416250081&sr=1-1&keywords=SQL+Server+internals&pebp=1416250085573

Comment: @HLGEM I'm a researcher in a non-database field and want to add similar behavior to my own application - it's not the core of it, but I do not want to comprimise experimental results by unnecessarily inefficient code. Instead of reinventing the wheel, I thought I should find out how databases handle this problem. Hence there is no preferred database. Neither am I intersted too strongly in most other database core problems. It's mostly about this single question

Comment: Since differnt databases may solve the problem differently, that is why I recommended reading in detail about the one you use.